# Add Column to datettime driven Groupby function

Tags: pandas, datetime, transform, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe;

```
index   UoW Category Description    Date    Channel Trans
ADATE                   
2018-12-31  1603    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  AustPost    209
2018-12-31  1604    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  AustPost    14
2019-12-31  1605    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  CSC         234
2019-12-31  1606    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  CSC         1
2019-12-31  1607    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  DTMR Other  1
2018-12-31  1608    Pay Infringement    31/12/2018  Internet    496
2018-12-30  1609    Pay Infringement    30/12/2018  CSC         266
```

I want to add column `df['MonthofYear']` after grouping by 'Channel' and 'Year'.

The following gives me the desired results without additional column

```
df['Trans'].groupby([df['Channel'],  df.index.year]).agg(['max', 'min'])
```

I tried:

```
 df['MonthofYear']=df['Trans'].groupby([df['Channel'],  df.index.year]).agg(['max', 'min']).transform(df.index.month)
```

Would appreciate help

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: do you want to replicate the grouped value in all the rows of the same group?

Comment: What I need returned ideally is the corresponding df.index.month of what is returned by the agg function.

Comment: The dataframe has over 12,000,000 rows. I need  to find the max and min value in each year for each channel. df['Trans'].groupby([df['Channel'],  df.index.year]).agg(['max', 'min']) realizes that. What I want though, is to identify which month the max and min value have been derived from.

Comment: Yes, need the min, max, and month column which should contain the month from which either value originated.

Comment: @wwnde - yop, now understand, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and 
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for datetimes from index by maximum and minumum values of `Trans` column and then convert values to months:

```
tup = [('MaxVal','max'),
       ('MinVal', 'min'), 
       ('MonthofYearMin', 'idxmin'),
       ('MonthofYearMax', 'idxmax')]
df1 = df.groupby(['Channel',  df.index.year.rename('year')])['Trans'].agg(tup)

df1['MonthofYearMax'] = df1['MonthofYearMax'].dt.month
df1['MonthofYearMin'] = df1['MonthofYearMin'].dt.month
print (df1)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, this returns an entire data frame though and not a breakdown of channel, year, max, min and month. I expected more of a stacked result.

Comment: @wwnde - Answer was edited. Friend advice - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: ,advice taken seriously. Solution worked very well. Will have to do more reading to understand how you utilize the tup (list). Not come across it. Very much appreciate your help. Cheers